# What does OpenSSL's EVP mean?

Tags: openssl

What does OpenSSL's EVP mean? I know it is a higher level crypto interface library in OpenSSL, but what do the letters E-V-P stand for?

Thanks,
Chenz

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This explanation from doc/ssleat.txt should give you enough of an
answer:

EVP The Digital **EnVeloPe** library is quite large.  At it's core are
    function to perform encryption and decryption by parts while using
    an initial parameter to specify which of the 17 different ciphers
    or 4 different message digests to use.  On top of these are implmented
    the digital signature functions, sign, verify, seal and open.
    Base64 encoding of binary data is also done in this library.

Answer (score 61):

Interesting question. I don't know for sure, but the `#ifndef` at the top of evp.h is:

```
#ifndef HEADER_ENVELOPE_H
```

So, I'm guessing **Envelope**.

Comment: Better guess than I could come up with.

Comment: That's right - the `EVP_*` functions are "envelope encryption".

Comment: It is in the [docs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) now.