# where is SHA1_Init implementation in openssl

Tags: openssl, sha

I would like to find the implementation of SHA1_Init in openssl source code.

http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/sha/sha1.c#0108

```
0108     SHA1_Init(&c);
```

but only definition found in 
http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/sha/sha.h#0122

Where is it?
Thanks,

=SG=

Answer (score 1):

So `SHA1_Init` is defined in the [header of `sha_locl.h`](http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/sha/sha_locl.h#0095) as `HASH_INIT`. [`sha1dgst.c` includes `sha_locl.h`](http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/sha/sha1dgst.c#0072) which includes [`../md32_common.h`](http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/md32_common.h) which does the expansion of `HASH_UPDATE`, `HASH_TRANFORM`, and `HASH_FINAL` which is defined as `SHA1_Init` in `sha.h`. I believe the actual implementation though of `SHA1_Init` is ultimately here: http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/sha/sha_locl.h#0125 or here on github: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/sha_locl.h#L101.

Comment: If this is correct would you mind marking it as so? Thanks! @smokinggun

Answer (score 0):

Note: starting with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), you would no longer find `SHA1_Init(&c)` used: Git 2.42 adjusts to OpenSSL 3+, which deprecates its SHA-1 functions based on its traditional API, by using its [EVP API](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) instead.

See "[What does OpenSSL's EVP (Envelope Cryptography) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3055454/6309)", and "[Encrypting/Decrypting a file using OpenSSL EVP](https://medium.com/@amit.kulkarni/encrypting-decrypting-a-file-using-openssl-evp-b26e0e4d28d4)" by [Amit Kulkarni](https://github.com/kulkarniamit).

See [commit bda9c12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bda9c12073e786e2ffa2c3ec479c7fe098d49999), [commit 3e440ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e440ea0aba0660f356a3e5b9fc366d5d6960847) (01 Aug 2023) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 889c94d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/889c94d2a0f4041c8237044db1d7ffd0190a2e0f), 09 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bda9c12073`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bda9c12073e786e2ffa2c3ec479c7fe098d49999):avoid SHA-1 functions deprecated in OpenSSL 3+
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Wong</sup>

> OpenSSL 3+ deprecates the `SHA1_Init,` `SHA1_Update,` and `SHA1_Final` functions, leading to errors when building with `DEVELOPER=1'.
>
> Use the newer `EVP_*` API with OpenSSL 3+ (only) despite being more error-prone and less efficient due to heap allocations.

For instance, you would now have, instead of using directly `SHA1_Init(&c)`:

```cpp
static inline void openssl_SHA1_Init(struct openssl_SHA1_CTX *ctx)
{
    const EVP_MD *type = EVP_sha1();

    ctx->ectx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx->ectx)
        die("EVP_MD_CTX_new: out of memory");

    EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx->ectx, type, NULL);
}
```

With `EVP_DigestInit_ex()` being defined in [`openssl/openssl` `crypto/evp/digest.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/45c02183c65f0e1abf59909c2900764606334664/crypto/evp/digest.c#L381)